# how to sum of two multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am new in php. i need sum of two arrays but not getting right output.my arrays are coming in this way.

this is my first array.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [-10] => 21787048.7293
                    [-5] => 21816115.9548
                    [-1] => 21839369.7352
                    [0] => 21845183.1803
                    [1] => 21850996.6254
                    [5] => 21874250.4058
                    [10] => 21903317.6313
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [-10] => 21147607.6407
                    [-5] => 21496395.4105
                    [-1] => 21775425.6263
                    [0] => 21845183.1803
                    [1] => 21914940.7343
                    [5] => 22193970.9501
                    [10] => 22542758.7199
                )

        )

)
```

and this is second array.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [-10] => 26101989.9443
                    [-5] => 26131057.1698
                    [-1] => 26154310.9501
                    [0] => 26160124.3952
                    [1] => 26165937.8403
                    [5] => 26189191.6207
                    [10] => 26218258.8462
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [-10] => 25462548.8556
                    [-5] => 25811336.6254
                    [-1] => 26090366.8413
                    [0] => 26160124.3952
                    [1] => 26229881.9492
                    [5] => 26508912.1651
                    [10] => 26857699.9349
                )

        )

)
```

i need sum of these two arrays by keys.please help me out.

this is my code.my two arrays are $pretax_income, $earning.

```
foreach($pretax_income as $k=>$value)
        {
          foreach($value as $v=>$val)
          {
            foreach($val as $u=>$valArr) {
            $comboarray[$elno] = $valArr[$k][$v][$u] + $earning[$k][$v][$u];

            }   
          } 


        }   print_r($comboarray);
```

Comment: **but not getting right output** - show us what you attempted then so we can see where you went wrong. Show your _php code_.

Comment: Why are You using three `foreach` loops when only **TWO** are needed? And where is the `$elno` variable comming from? Also checking whether the indexes exist also in the second array would be nice habit to get used to otherwise You may end with many warnings and/or notices unless You are certain that both arrays are the same only with different values in the most inner one...

Comment: You might make some better off of your initial arrays, eg, using good indices, such as zero stating index as good PHP usage, avoiding useless depth of dimensions... And then it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
foreach($pretax_income as $key1=>$val1){
  foreach($val1 as $key2=>$val2){
    foreach($val2 as $key3=>$val3){
      $comboarray[$key1][$key2][$key3]=$pretax_income[$key1][$key2][$key3]+$earning[$key1][$key2][$key3];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum()
{
    $identicalKeysArrays = func_get_args();

    if (is_array($identicalKeysArrays[0])) {
        $result = call_user_func_array('sum', array_map(function ($array) {
            return $array[0];
        }, $identicalKeysArrays));

        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    if ($identicalKeysArrays[0]) {
        $summed = array();
        foreach ($identicalKeysArrays as $array) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $summed[$key] = ($summed[$key] ? $summed[$key] : 0) + $value;
            }

        }

        return $summed;
    }
}

$a = array(array(
    '-1' => 23,
    '2'  => 2
));

$b = array(array(
    '-1' => 3
));

var_dump(sum($a, $b));
```

Result:
array(2) { [-1]=> int(26) [2]=> int(2) }